# Uninitialized Constant from Gemfile

Tags: ruby, require, gemfile

Just playing around with Ruby and have this very basic example

`runner.rb`:

```
require "bundler/setup"
include Mongo

mongo_client = MongoClient.new("localhost", 27017)
#mongo_client.database_names # lists all database names
#mongo_client.database_info.each { |info| puts info.inspect }

db = mongo_client.db("james_safety")

coll = db.collection("safety")

puts "above"

10.times { |i| coll.insert("i" => i) }


puts "Hello World"
```

`Gemfile`:

```
source :rubygems
gem 'mongo'
```

`bundle` output:

```
Using bson (1.8.2) 
Using mongo (1.8.2) 
Using bundler (1.2.2) 
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

When I try to run `ruby runner.rb`, I get this error:

```
/Users/Tyler/Development/Ruby/JamesSaftey/runner.rb:2:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Mongo (NameError)
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

If I `require 'mongo'` in `runner.rb`, it works just fine (I installed the gem outside of the Gemfile).

I also tried `require 'rubygems'`.  No difference.

Am I just misconfiguring my ruby file to use the Gemfile?

Ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if a gem is in the gemfile, you need to require it, or do the following in your ruby file so all the bundled gems are required :

```
Bundler.require(:default)
```

[More infos here](http://gembundler.com/rationale.html)

Comment: The first part (just adding the `require` to the `Gemfile` did not work), however, adding `Bundler.require(:default)` to the ruby file did work.  Thanks

Comment: My bad, the first part just indicates to bundler which file to require if it differs from the gem name. Editing ...